# Azure migration of resources using MigAz tool

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am planning to migrate my Azure resources from EA type of subscription to C-S-P subscription. I found a tool called as Migrate Azure(sorry cannot write the short form as this does not allow me to post). I am aware of its working, however i am just worried about one that.

Can the migration cause a downtime into any working of any resources like Azure Virtual machine, storage...etc. Point is i will be directly working on the production resources to migrate to the C-S-P subscription.

Can anyone give me an idea ?

Comment: follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/migration/ea-payg-to-azure-csp/partner-ea-to-csp not sure about any tool that you are using

Comment: Hello Hari I am using the migAz tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @HariHaran, you should follow the documentation mentioned in [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/migration/ea-payg-to-azure-csp/partner-ea-to-csp) 
The subscription switching should not affect your workloads, since it's a subscription migration and not workload related(Assuming that all of your resources already reside in Azure). The safe approach to follow during your migration process is to do it incrementally. Then if all functions as normal, increase the migration rate. Do it all at once may not be the best. Redeployment issues can occur at times.

Comment: Hello adam thanks for your reply. I have got the gist of migration now from the information provided by you and Hari. The tool which i am referring to is the migAz tool mentioned here http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=19762